# Invite user's friends to a facebook event through a web page

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I have an an existing event under a facebook fan page. I'm making a web page for the event and i'd like to make users of the web page able to invite their friends to the event.

I'm thinking of some king of a dialog, but not about inviting friends to like a page or use an app, but to add them to the invited people list of the event.

It would be great to also track if a user has invited his friends or how many did he invite.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/event/invited

> You cannot invite people to events via the Graph API.

There is also no dialog for this, event invites are only possible on Facebook. Obviously, that means you can´t track if a user has invited his friends or many of them.